# How to add time to a video with the initial frame

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to add 1 second to my video from beginning of it with the first frame. I mean the video will play 1 second length first frame before it starts. I am wondering how to do this with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]trim=end_frame=1[i];[0]setpts=PTS+1/TB[m];[i][m]overlay" out.mp4
```

Audio is ignored. To delay audio as well,

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]trim=end_frame=1[i];[0]setpts=PTS+1/TB[m];[i][m]overlay" -af "adelay=1000|1000" out.mp4
```

Comment: It added the frame but lowered the quality of the video significantly. I want to keep all video specs as it is.

Comment: Add `-crf 20`.  Try lower values till it is ok.